# Foundation reveal modal won't open

Tags: zurb-foundation

When you click the "client login" link at the top of [this page](https://nataliecardot.com/zeus-hosting/index.html#), the reveal modal should appear. The HTML for it is correct for sure, so a script must be wrong.

In the head of my page, I have these scripts/link:

```
<!-- jQuery in case needed for Foundation -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Foundation CDN Links -->
    <!-- Compressed CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.3/dist/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-GSio8qamaXapM8Fq9JYdGNTvk/dgs+cMLgPeevOYEx0= sha384-wAweiGTn38CY2DSwAaEffed6iMeflc0FMiuptanbN4J+ib+342gKGpvYRWubPd/+ sha512-QHEb6jOC8SaGTmYmGU19u2FhIfeG+t/hSacIWPpDzOp5yygnthL3JwnilM7LM1dOAbJv62R+/FICfsrKUqv4Gg==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Compressed JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.5.3/dist/js/foundation.min.js" integrity="sha256-mRYlCu5EG+ouD07WxLF8v4ZAZYCA6WrmdIXyn1Bv9Vk= sha384-KzKofw4qqetd3kvuQ5AdapWPqV1ZI+CnfyfEwZQgPk8poOLWaabfgJOfmW7uI+AV sha512-0gHfaMkY+Do568TgjJC2iMAV0dQlY4NqbeZ4pr9lVUTXQzKu8qceyd6wg/3Uql9qA2+3X5NHv3IMb05wb387rA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The compressed CSS and JavaScript are what Foundation says to use.

I created the project with foundation-cli originally but am unable to deploy, so I copied all the static files/minified CSS into this new GitHub repo and published with GitHub Pages without issue: https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting
If I can't simply use CDN links for the reveal modal to work, maybe I could copy the needed files from the [original project's repo](https://github.com/nataliecardot/zeus-hosting-setup) (created by running `foundation new`).

Here's the HTML of the reveal modal, although I know it's correct:

```
<div class="reveal login-modal" id="loginModal" data-reveal>
      <h1 class="h3">Client Login</h1>
      <form>
        <label><input type="text" placeholder="Username"></label>
        <label><input type="password" placeholder="Password"></label>
        <div class="login-bottom-group">
          <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
          <div class="login-couple">
            <span>Remember Me</span>
            <div class="switch">
              <input class="switch-input" id="rememberSwitch" type="checkbox" name="rememberSwitch">
              <label class="switch-paddle" for="rememberSwitch">
                <span class="show-for-sr">Remember Me</span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, please use the `zurb-foundation` tag next time, `foundation` is a macOS framework =)

Comment: I added these script links and files from the original project created by running `foundation new` and the modal is now opening: `<script src="node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.js"></script>` as well as the file `<script src="js/app.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Scripts have to be and should always be at the end of `<body>`, right before `</body>`.